# Trying to use simple authentication in Play Framework, but my action is called twice

Tags: java, authentication, playframework, playframework-2.1

I used the samples to add simple authentication to my app. with the annotation of:

```
 @Security.Authenticated(ShlangAuthenticator.class)
public static Result processShlangCommand()
```

And the class ShlangAuthenticator is based on the sample:

```
public class ShlangAuthenticator extends Security.Authenticator {

@Override
public String getUsername(Context ctx)
{
    String s = ctx.session().get("email"); 
    System.err.println("getUsernameCalled: " + s);
    return s;
}

@Override
public Result onUnauthorized(Context ctx)
{

    System.err.println("onUnauthorized called");
    return redirect("http://localhost/#/login");

}
```

}

The problem I am getting is that every call to the Action (processShlangCommand() ) is being called twice by play (Play 2.1.1), I printed the stack trace and it seems to be identical. Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps it's because you're using System.err to log, instead of the default logger in play? Regardless, for authentication, I'm using this module: https://github.com/joscha/play-authenticate

Comment: Thanks, indeed removing the System.err.println solved the problem. I am not sure I understand why though, and I always want to understand the why (and how) things work.